# How to route to different extensions

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am new to asterisk and I would like to do a simple routing job

I have configured asterisk to have 3 sip ddi numbers

Below sip.conf:

```
[0001]
type=peer
fromuser=4420XXXX0001
host=X.X.X.X
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
insecure=invite
context=default 

[0002]
type=peer
fromuser=4420XXXX0002
host=X.X.X.X
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
insecure=invite
context=default

[0003]
type=peer
fromuser=4420XXXX0003
host=X.X.X.X
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
insecure=invite
context=default
```

At the moment if I make a call I always use the first DDI 4420XXXX0001 which is the first extension number

Below extensions.conf

```
[default]

;Outgoing Number 0001
exten => _44.,1,Noop(CALLERID:${CALLERID})
exten => _44.,n,Set(CALLERID(all)="My Name"<+4420XXXX0001>)
exten => _44.,n,Dial(SIP/+${EXTEN:2}@0001)
exten => _44.,n,Hangup

;Outgoing Number 0002
exten => _44.,1,Noop(CALLERID:${CALLERID})
exten => _44.,n,Set(CALLERID(all)="My Name"<+4420XXXX0002>)
exten => _44.,n,Dial(SIP/+${EXTEN:2}@0002)
exten => _44.,n,Hangup

;Outgoing Number 0003
exten => _44.,1,Noop(CALLERID:${CALLERID})
exten => _44.,n,Set(CALLERID(all)="My Name"<+4420XXXX0003>)
exten => _44.,n,Dial(SIP/+${EXTEN:2}@0003)
exten => _44.,n,Hangup
```

How can I route this out in order to use different lines and different caller ids

I apologise for the naming conventions I find difficult to explain this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read any asterisk book. This one topic at start of book, really

There are alot of posible variant how to balance trunks. For example this one is random balancing of 3 trunks.

```
[gate];начальный контекст
exten => _7XXXXXXXXXX,1,Set(num=${EXTEN})
exten => _7XXXXXXXXXX,2,Goto(gate_variants,${RAND(1,6)},1)
[gate_variants];все допустимые варианты
exten => 1,1,Set(DO=1-2-3)
exten => 2,1,Set(DO=1-3-2)
exten => 3,1,Set(DO=2-1-3)
exten => 4,1,Set(DO=2-3-1)
exten => 5,1,Set(DO=3-1-2)
exten => 6,1,Set(DO=3-2-1)
exten => _[1-6],2,goto(s,1)

exten => s,1,Set(i=0); делаем цикл(я это не писал, это у меня стандартная заготовка ;) )
exten => s,n(loop),Set(i=$[ i + 1]) ; смотрим по номеру
exten => s,n,Set(do_now=${CUT(DO,-,${i}) ; берем и-тый номер.
exten => s,n,GotoIF($[ "${do_now}" == "" ]?end); номера кончилися ((
exten => s,n,Dial(IAX2/manager${do_now}/${num},,g) ; звоним
exten => s,n,Goto({DIALSTATUS},1); проверяем результат
exten => s,n(end),Hangup; больше нет номеров

exten => BUSY,1,Goto(s,loop); повторяем
exten => CONGESTION,1,Goto(s,loop)
exten => FAIL,1,Goto(s,loop)
exten => NOANSWER,1,Goto(s,loop)

exten => ANSWER,1,Hangup;это не повторям, вроде дозвонилися.
exten => ANSWERED,1,Hangup
```

http://asterisk-support.ru/question/13916/dialplan-balansirovka-i-tsikl-mezhdu-trankami/#19951